# Oracle Sql collection columns in where statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I want to extract data from tableA based on a column stored inside an apex collection:

```
 SELECT c001, c002, c003
 FROM apex_collections
 WHERE collection_name = 'CollectionA';
```

Column c001 contains data that I want to map to another table like:

```
 SELECT ID, Name, Country
 FROM my_table
 WHERE ID = c001;
```

How can I combine both tables based on an apex collection column?

Comment: Pls provide sample data and expected output. Pls share with us on what you've tried as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a join, I guess.

```
select m.id, m.name, m.country
from my_table m join apex_collections c on c.c001 = m.id
where c.collection_name = 'CollectionA';
```

If you'll use it in PL/SQL, you'll need an `INTO` clause (as you have to put selected values *into something*). If you'll use such a query in a cursor `FOR` loop, then ... well, it depends on what you'll do next.